# Why isn't the returned parameter of my chain being partially applied to the next task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, celery

I'm writing a chain which transforms some JSON into a URI based on its contents and then POSTs data to that URI. I'd like to do this asynchronously with Celery and know that grouping the chains will allow me to do this easily.

I have the following tasks written:

```
import time    

from celery import group, chain
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

from app import celery

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@celery.task
def create_uri(obj_json, endpoint):
    uri = "{0}:{1}/{2}".format(
        obj_json["host"],
        obj_json["port"],
        endpoint
    )
    logger.debug("Created host {0} from {1}".format(uri, obj_json))
    return uri

@celery.task
def send_post(uri, data):
    logger.debug("Posting {0} to {1}...".format(data, uri))
    return uri

def send_messages(objs, endpoint, data):
    chains = [
         # The next line is causing problems.
        (create_uri.s(obj, endpoint) | send_post.s(data))
        for obj in objs
    ]
    g = group(*chains)
    res = g.apply_async(queue="default")
    while not res.ready():
       time.sleep(1)
    uris = res.get()
    print("Posted to {0}".format(uris))
    return uris
```

I find, however, when I try to use this, the `create_uri` bit of the chains finishes, but `send_post` is never called in my chain. This is strange, because I'm [following the docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives) bit about chains and, indeed, am nearly following the example shown [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) about avoiding synchronous jobs.

I'm running my workers with

```
celery worker -A celery_worker.celery -l debug -c 5 -Q default
```

where `celery_worker` simply pushes the app context and imports `app.celery`.

and my config looks like this:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

A line from my logs is:

> [2017-01-09 12:35:59,298: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply  (args:(**'app.tasks.create_uri'**, '197f4836-1cd8-4f7f-adaf-b8cebdb304ef', {'timelimit': [None, None], 'group': None, 'parent_id': None, 'retries': 0, 'argsrepr': **"({'port': 8079, 'host': 'localhost'}, 'start')"**, 'lang': 'py', 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'delivery_info': {'routing_key': 'default', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': None, 'exchange': ''}, 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'task': 'app.tasks.create_uri', 'root_id': '197f4836-1cd8-4f7f-adaf-b8cebdb304ef', 'correlation_id': '197f4836-1cd8-4f7f-adaf-b8cebdb304ef', 'origin': 'foobar', 'reply_to': '6559d43e-6cae-3b6f-89be-7b80e2a43098', 'id': '197f4836-1cd8-4f7f-adaf-b8cebdb304ef'}, b'[[{"port": 8079, "host": "localhost"}, "start"], {}, {"chord": null, "callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, **"chain": [{"task": "app.tasks.send_post", "subtask_type": null, "options": {"group_id": "60c2c9b2-eb51-457d-b248-b8e5552e0fd8", "task_id":... kwargs:{}**)

When I print `chains[0].tasks`, I see this:

```
(app.tasks.create_uri({'host': 'localhost', 'port': 8079}, 'start'), 
 app.tasks.send_post({'hello': 'world'}))
```

It is recognizing that `send_post` is the next task in the chain, but the task is never being accepted.

Why is my `group` hanging after finishing the first tasks in the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating chains and groups correctly. However tasks send to invalid queues won't be recognised by workers. When you do `.get()` on them, they hang forever as it will never return result.

So, you can use default `celery` queue

```
res = g.apply_async().get()

# explicit
res = g.apply_async(queue="celery").get()
```

Or configure routing properly and then use custom queue.

```
res = g.apply_async(queue='foo').get()
```

Comment: `queue` is a kwarg to `apply_async`. Can provide link to docs later.

Comment: See [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#routing-options).

Comment: The queue `default` you are setting doesn't exists or you have not configured queues properly. I thought if you configure it properly, it should work.

Comment: You were right -- I apologize. I'm going to edit your answer slightly to remove the downvote. I had not added my new queue using `add_consumer`.

Comment: I do find some strange behavior though: I add a consumer and list the queue name in `apply_async`, but it seems to always consume from the default `queue="celery"` consumer.

Comment: Ah, silly mistake number 2: just required a redis restart. :) Thanks for the help!